# Can't get divs aligned

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align 3 divs next to each other with is partially working but I'm trying to set the width based on % of the screen but if it's make all the divs width add up to 100% it doesn't fit all on one line. Please see below

[image: This shows what it looks like on my monitor]

Here is the html code I'm using

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<div id='donate' class="hero-unit" style="width:20%; height:200px; margin-left:15px; Float:left">
<h1 style="font-size:35px;">Donate</h1>
<p>Interested in supporting us? Click below for more information</p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" link href="http://www.universalpvp.com">
Learn more &raquo;
</a>
</p>
</div>
<center>
<div id='forum' class="hero-unit" style="width:60%; height:200px; Float:left;">
<h1 style="font-size:35px;">Forum</h1>
<p>Want to talk to other members? Click below</p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" link href="http://www.universalpvp.com">
Learn more &raquo;
</a>
</p>
</div>
</center>
<div id='info' class="hero-unit" style="width:20%; height:200px; margin-right:15px; Float:right">
<h1 style="font-size:35px;">Server Information</h1>
<p>Click below for more information about the server</p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="http://www.universalpvp.com">
Learn more &raquo;
</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help me make this work so it fits on all size monitors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your widths total 100% but you also have margins applied which is causing the div to jump down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your total page width is 100%. At most, the three  can be a maximum of 33%. However, I see that you also want them to have some margin on the left and right of the group of three.

You don't even need the parent `<div>` that says `width: 100%;`

Try this:

```
<div id='donate' class="hero-unit" style="width:18%; height:200px; margin-left:2%; float:left">
<h1 style="font-size:35px;">Donate</h1>
<p>Interested in supporting us? Click below for more information</p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" link href="http://www.universalpvp.com">
Learn more &raquo;
</a>
</p>
</div>
<center>
<div id='forum' class="hero-unit" style="width:58% !important; height:200px; float:left;">
<h1 style="font-size:35px;">Forum</h1>
<p>Want to talk to other members? Click below</p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" link href="http://www.universalpvp.com">
Learn more &raquo;
</a>
</p>
</div>
</center>
<div id='info' class="hero-unit" style="width:18%; height:200px; margin-right:2%; float: left;">
<h1 style="font-size:35px;">Server Information</h1>
<p>Click below for more information about the server</p>
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="http://www.universalpvp.com">
Learn more &raquo;
</a>
</p>
</div>
```

You can now toy around with the % values but make sure they don't exceed 100% (width and margin combined). If it still doesn't work, you may have some other styling affecting how the `<div>`s are getting displayed.

[image: This is what it would look like]

Comment: I have just tried this but it still goes onto a separate line.

Comment: Try it now. There was a problem with "float"

Comment: In fact you don't even need the parent `<div>` that says `width: 100%`

Comment: It still does the same thing the forum div is very long - http://prntscr.com/vmmbk

Comment: I just updated the code again but it's still not working - Here is the whole html code http://pastebin.com/hzPBmF96

Comment: When I remove the bootstrap stylesheet it aligns perfectly. What would cause this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25888/discussion-between-karancan-and-dcsoft)